# Jetstream with Liviwere - Laravel 8 - Node vulnerabilities when run npm install

Tags: npm, laravel-8, laravel-mix, postcss, laravel-jetstream

I install Laravel 8 with Jetstream and Livewire using Sail.

When I ran the command `npm install` returned in the screen:

```
99 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

34 moderate severity vulnerabilities
```

So, I ran the command `npm audit`:

```
postcss  7.0.0 - 8.2.9
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1693
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install laravel-mix@5.0.9, which is a breaking change
node_modules/@types/cssnano/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/css-declaration-sorter/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/cssnano-preset-default/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/cssnano-util-raw-cache/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-calc/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-colormin/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-convert-values/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-discard-comments/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-discard-duplicates/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-discard-empty/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-discard-overridden/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-merge-longhand/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-merge-rules/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-minify-font-values/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-minify-gradients/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-minify-params/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-minify-selectors/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-charset/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-display-values/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-positions/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-repeat-style/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-string/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-timing-functions/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-unicode/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-url/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-whitespace/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-ordered-values/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-reduce-initial/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-reduce-transforms/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-svgo/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-unique-selectors/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/stylehacks/node_modules/postcss
  css-declaration-sorter  4.0.0 - 5.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-declaration-sorter
  cssnano  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.1.1 - 4.1.11
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/cssnano
    laravel-mix  5.0.8 || >=6.0.0-alpha.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano
    node_modules/laravel-mix
  cssnano-preset-default  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano-util-raw-cache
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-minify-gradients
  node_modules/cssnano-preset-default
  cssnano-util-raw-cache  >=4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/cssnano-util-raw-cache
  postcss-calc  6.0.2 - 7.0.5
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-calc
  postcss-colormin  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-colormin
  postcss-convert-values  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-convert-values
  postcss-discard-comments  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-comments
  postcss-discard-duplicates  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-duplicates
  postcss-discard-empty  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-empty
  postcss-discard-overridden  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-overridden
  postcss-merge-longhand  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.6 - 4.0.11
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-merge-longhand
  postcss-merge-rules  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-merge-rules
  postcss-minify-font-values  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-font-values
  postcss-minify-gradients  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-gradients
  postcss-minify-params  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-params
  postcss-minify-selectors  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-selectors
  postcss-normalize-charset  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-charset
  postcss-normalize-display-values  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-display-values
  postcss-normalize-positions  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-positions
  postcss-normalize-repeat-style  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-repeat-style
  postcss-normalize-string  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-string
  postcss-normalize-timing-functions  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-timing-functions
  postcss-normalize-unicode  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-unicode
  postcss-normalize-url  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-url
  postcss-normalize-whitespace  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-whitespace
  postcss-ordered-values  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.1.1 - 4.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-ordered-values
  postcss-reduce-initial  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-reduce-initial
  postcss-reduce-transforms  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-reduce-transforms
  postcss-svgo  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-svgo
  postcss-unique-selectors  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-unique-selectors
  stylehacks  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/stylehacks
```

Searching in GitHub issues from laravel-mix, I saw a update in laravel-mix about cssnano which depends of postcss.

I tried to run `npm update` and `npm upgrade`

But, when I open the package.json inside `node_modules\laravel-mix\package.json` the content is diferent compared to the GitHub ([Laravel-mix](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix)). My local file has old versions from cssnano and missing files but the version of laravel-mix is correct.

```
{
    "name": "laravel-mix",
    "version": "6.0.19",
    "description": "The power of webpack, distilled for the rest of us.",
    "main": "src/index.js",
    "types": "types/index.d.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "mix": "./bin/cli.js",
        "test": "ava --verbose --serial --timeout=30s",
        "eslint": "eslint setup/ src/ test/ --max-warnings=0"
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged"
        }
    },
    "ava": {
        "require": [
            "esm"
        ]
    },
    "bin": {
        "mix": "./bin/cli.js",
        "laravel-mix": "./bin/cli.js"
    },
    "repository": "JeffreyWay/laravel-mix",
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix#readme",
    "keywords": [
        "laravel",
        "webpack",
        "laravel elixir",
        "laravel mix"
    ],
    "author": "Jeffrey Way",
    "license": "MIT",
    "files": [
        "icons",
        "setup",
        "src",
        "types"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.1",
        "@types/babel__core": "^7.1.12",
        "@types/browser-sync": "^2.26.1",
        "@types/clean-css": "^4.2.2",
        "@types/cssnano": "^4.0.0",
        "@types/imagemin-gifsicle": "^7.0.0",
        "@types/imagemin-mozjpeg": "^8.0.0",
        "@types/imagemin-optipng": "^5.2.0",
        "@types/imagemin-svgo": "^8.0.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
        "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
        "chalk": "^4.1.0",
        "chokidar": "^3.4.3",
        "clean-css": "^4.2.3 || ^5.1.1",
        "cli-table3": "^0.6.0",
        "collect.js": "^4.28.4",
        "commander": "^7.1.0",
        "concat": "^1.0.3",
        "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "cssnano": "^4.1.11",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "dotenv-expand": "^5.1.0",
        "file-loader": "^6.1.1",
        "fs-extra": "^9.0.1",
        "glob": "^7.1.6",
        "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
        "imagemin": "^7.0.1",
        "img-loader": "^3.0.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.20",
        "md5": "^2.3.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.1.0",
        "node-libs-browser": "^2.2.1",
        "postcss-load-config": "^3.0.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^5.2.0",
        "semver": "^7.3.4",
        "strip-ansi": "^6.0.0",
        "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "terser": "^5.3.7",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
        "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.3",
        "webpack": "^5.25.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "4.0.0-beta.2",
        "webpack-merge": "^5.2.0",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.8.0",
        "webpackbar": "^5.0.0-3",
        "yargs": "^16.1.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
        "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.0-beta.0",
        "@types/fs-extra": "^9.0.8",
        "@types/koa": "^2.13.1",
        "@types/koa-static": "^4.0.1",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
        "@types/mock-require": "^2.0.0",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
        "@types/semver": "^7.3.4",
        "@types/sinon": "^9.0.11",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.1",
        "ava": "^3.13.0",
        "browserslist": "^4.16.0",
        "coffee-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "coffeescript": "^2.5.1",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "eol": "^0.9.1",
        "eslint": "^7.11.0",
        "esm": "^3.2.25",
        "husky": "^4.3.0",
        "koa": "^2.13.0",
        "koa-static": "^5.0.0",
        "less": "^3.12.2 || ^4.0.0",
        "less-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "mock-require": "^3.0.3",
        "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
        "playwright": "^1.10.0",
        "postcss": "^8.1.2",
        "postcss-custom-properties": "^11.0.0",
        "prettier": "^2.2.1",
        "pretty-quick": "^3.1.0",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-refresh": "^0.9.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.1",
        "sass": "^1.27.0",
        "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
        "sass-resources-loader": "^2.1.1",
        "sinon": "^9.2.0",
        "stylus": "^0.54.8",
        "stylus-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "temp-sandbox": "^4.0.1",
        "ts-loader": "^8.0.18",
        "typescript": "^4.2.3",
        "vue-loader15": "npm:vue-loader@^15.9.1",
        "vue-loader16": "npm:vue-loader@^16.1.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "vue2": "npm:vue@^2.6.12",
        "vue3": "npm:vue@^3.0.1"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "postcss": "^8.1.2"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=12.14.0"
    }
}
```

Extra information about postcss:

```
html@ /var/www/html
+-- laravel-mix@6.0.19
| +-- @types/cssnano@4.0.0
| | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| +-- autoprefixer@10.2.6
| | `-- postcss@8.3.0 deduped
| +-- css-loader@5.2.6
| | +-- icss-utils@5.1.0
| | | `-- postcss@8.3.0 deduped
| | +-- postcss-modules-extract-imports@3.0.0
| | | `-- postcss@8.3.0 deduped
| | +-- postcss-modules-local-by-default@4.0.0
| | | `-- postcss@8.3.0 deduped
| | +-- postcss-modules-scope@3.0.0
| | | `-- postcss@8.3.0 deduped
| | +-- postcss-modules-values@4.0.0
| | | `-- postcss@8.3.0 deduped
| | `-- postcss@8.3.0 deduped
| +-- cssnano@4.1.11
| | +-- cssnano-preset-default@4.0.8
| | | +-- css-declaration-sorter@4.0.1
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- cssnano-util-raw-cache@4.0.1
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-calc@7.0.5
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-colormin@4.0.3
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-convert-values@4.0.1
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-discard-comments@4.0.2
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-discard-duplicates@4.0.2
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-discard-empty@4.0.1
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-discard-overridden@4.0.1
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-merge-longhand@4.0.11
| | | | +-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | | `-- stylehacks@4.0.3
| | | |   `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-merge-rules@4.0.3
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-minify-font-values@4.0.2
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-minify-gradients@4.0.2
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-minify-params@4.0.2
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-minify-selectors@4.0.2
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-normalize-charset@4.0.1
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-normalize-display-values@4.0.2
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-normalize-positions@4.0.2
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-normalize-repeat-style@4.0.2
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-normalize-string@4.0.2
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-normalize-timing-functions@4.0.2
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-normalize-unicode@4.0.1
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-normalize-url@4.0.1
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-normalize-whitespace@4.0.2
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-ordered-values@4.1.2
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-reduce-initial@4.0.3
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-reduce-transforms@4.0.2
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-svgo@4.0.3
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | +-- postcss-unique-selectors@4.0.1
| | | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| | `-- postcss@7.0.35
| +-- postcss-loader@5.3.0
| | `-- postcss@8.3.0 deduped
| `-- postcss@8.3.0 deduped
+-- postcss-import@14.0.2
| `-- postcss@8.3.0 deduped
+-- postcss@8.3.0
`-- tailwindcss@2.1.4
  +-- @fullhuman/postcss-purgecss@3.1.3
  | `-- purgecss@3.1.3
  |   `-- postcss@8.3.0 deduped
  +-- postcss-functions@3.0.0
  | `-- postcss@6.0.23
  +-- postcss-js@3.0.3
  | `-- postcss@8.3.0 deduped
  +-- postcss-nested@5.0.5
  | `-- postcss@8.3.0 deduped
  `-- postcss@8.3.0 deduped
```

I dont know what to do, I need help.

Answer (score 1):

For solve the problem, just force the npm install via github.

```
npm install https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix\#master
```